# How to import content for content types with user-defined fields

Tags: 7, feeds, importing-exporting

I've got a large amount of data I would like to turn into pages in Drupal. Most of the data to import correspond to custom fields I created in a new content type (let's call it *directory*).

For example, I have things like zip code, address, state, etc. that I would like to import as *directory* content.

I've been working with the feeds module, but so far I haven't been able to figure out if it can map to custom fields in a content type (I'm beginning to suspect that it cannot).

I'm using Drupal 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) just needed a bit of time to add the required functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look into [migrate module](http://drupal.org/project/migrate/). This module is very flexible, very well documented and can  easily handle  and ease the pains of content migration.  Custom content, users, comments, etc .. and just about whatever you throw at it can be set up as 'migration tasks'.

Good-luck!

Comment: Cute kid :) I got an error when I attempted to install the module, and now I can't uninstall it. I'm putting the error in a separate comment to make it easier to read.

Comment: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.migrate_status' doesn't exist: SELECT ms.class_name AS class_name FROM {migrate_status} ms; Array ( ) in migrate_flush_caches() (line 133 of /pathtodrupal/sites/all/modules/migrate/migrate.module).

Comment: You are on mysql? I would try removing the entry of the module from the system table, if you can either get from the command line the following sql result: "select * from system where type ="module" and name like "migrat%"; , you should see the entry you have to delete.  We have used this module quite extensively in the past, I'm quite surprised you have that error.

Comment: The install simply failed to create the table for some reason, I would even try looking at the schema and loading it manually, or see why it's choking.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Feeds really is what I was looking for; I was just looking a bit too soon.